# Email Templates ColdFusion9

Tags: html, email, coldfusion, html-email, coldfusion-9

I am having some issues with my email setup and hoping that someone in here encountered something similar before.

I am using CF9 to begin with. I have an email template which I'm using to send different emails with dynamic content coming from a DB.

The emails are going out as HTML emails and I am using this as my header:

```
<!-- // Begin Module: Standard Header Image \\ -->
<img src="http://www.example.com/cf_modules/autoresponders/example/sf_email_head.jpg" 
style="border:0;height:150px;line-height:100%;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:600px;" 
id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" alt="Image" />
<!-- // End Module: Standard Header Image \\ -->
```

My issue is that sometime the image is not being displayed and when I inspect the code the link for the image becomes something like

```
src="../../autoresponders/example/sf_email_head.jpg"
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening and if it is an error in my coding why it doesn't show up in all of the emails that are being sent out?

Also, I forgot to mention that I am giving the user the option to edit the email with TinyMCE and as I read on forums sometimes this editor is converting URLs to links.
Im just waiting to see if my fix is working.

Comment: We need to see what the code the generates the email looks like. Please post that and we can tell you if there is something in the code causing it (which there most likely is)

Comment: TinyMCE was messing with my URLs 

I fixed it by adding 
 

    tinyMCE.init({ 
            // General options 
            mode : "textareas", 
      elements : "htmleditor",
            theme : "advanced", 
      **convert_urls : false**

Comment: @Crematorio - If answered your own question feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to do that. I have to wait for 5 more hours. I will port the answer as soon as I am allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE was messing with my URLs

I fixed it by adding

```
tinyMCE.init({ 
        // General options 
        mode : "textareas", 
        elements : "htmleditor",
        theme : "advanced", 
        convert_urls : false
```